# carousel bootstrap 4 somente no modo mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, aplicação-desktop, bootstrap-4

Dada a imagem a baixo que representa o modo desktop, gostaria de saber como faz para virar um carousel somente no modo mobile.

[image: quero que esses items no modo mobile vire um carousel,mas quando visualizar a tela no modo desktop fique deste jeito como da imagem]

```
!--- Team ----->


<div id="team" class="team">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 class="wow fadeInUp">Meet our team</h2>
            <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4">Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="2s">
                <img src="images/team/team-1.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="">
                <h4>John Doe</h4>
                <b>CEO and Founder</b>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  wow fadeInLeft"  data-wow-delay="1.6s">
                <img src="images/team/team-2.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="">
                <h4>John Doe</h4>
                <b>CEO and Founder</b>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  wow fadeInLeft"  data-wow-delay="1.2s">
                <img src="images/team/team-3.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="">
                <h4>John Doe</h4>
                <b>CEO and Founder</b>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  wow fadeInLeft" 0.8>
                <img src="images/team/team-4.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="">
                <h4>John Doe</h4>
                <b>CEO and Founder</b>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--- End Team ---->
```

Comment: E a sua pergunta é?

Comment: como que eu faço?

Comment: Como faz o que?

Comment: dada a imagem, gostaria de no modo mobile(somente) elas sejam exibidas no formato de carousel

Comment: Posta o resto relevante do se código, o postado não reflete a imagem de exemplo. E nem o cenário atual onde o problema ocorre.

Comment: O carousel tá funcionando?

Comment: tá sim, eu só queria fazer uma verificação if modo mobile ai sim habilita o carousel

Comment: Só adicione o atributo data-ride="carousel" na @mediaquery para mobile. Mas para um exemplo mais detalhado, coloque aqui o seu código html e js para verificar o comportamento e corrigir

Comment: Coloquei o código que é do html, ai tipo, tem esse modelo with controls:https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/ gostaria de tipo fazer ele aparecer só no mobile, tipo eu posso adicionar esse atributo data-ride="carousel" na <div id="team" class="team"> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz esse modelo com apenas algumas linhas de CSS. A ideia é deixar o "componente" do time estático apenas em telas grandes, e em telas pequena eu dou um `display:none` nele enquanto dou um `display:block` no *Slider*. *Logo com essa opção vc tem dois "componentes" ok.*

Veja o Exemplo funcionando: *(quando a tela for menor que 790px ele vai mostrar o Slider, mas se for maior ele mostra a lista estática.)* **Clique em "Página toda" para o *slider* sumir e ele ficar estático.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name=
 content=
>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    .carousel {
        display: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 790px) {
        .carousel {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .team {
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h2 class="wow fadeInUp">Meet our team</h2>
    <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4">Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
    <div id="team" class="team">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="2s">
                    <img src="http://placecage.com/150/150" class="img-circle" alt="">
                    <h4>John Doe</h4>
                    <b>CEO and Founder</b>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  wow fadeInLeft"  data-wow-delay="1.6s">
                    <img src="http://placecage.com/150/150" class="img-circle" alt="">
                    <h4>John Doe</h4>
                    <b>CEO and Founder</b>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  wow fadeInLeft"  data-wow-delay="1.2s">
                    <img src="http://placecage.com/150/150" class="img-circle" alt="">
                    <h4>John Doe</h4>
                    <b>CEO and Founder</b>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  wow fadeInLeft" 0.8>
                    <img src="http://placecage.com/150/150" class="img-circle" alt="">
                    <h4>John Doe</h4>
                    <b>CEO and Founder</b>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="col-lg-12 wow fadeInLeft" 0.8>
                <img src="http://placecage.com/150/150" class="img-circle" alt="">
                <h4>John Doe</h4>
                <b>CEO and Founder</b>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-lg-12 wow fadeInLeft" 0.8>
                <img src="http://placecage.com/150/150" class="img-circle" alt="">
                <h4>John Doe 2</h4>
                <b>CEO and Founder</b>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-lg-12 wow fadeInLeft" 0.8>
                <img src="http://placecage.com/150/150" class="img-circle" alt="">
                <h4>John Doe 3</h4>
                <b>CEO and Founder</b>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 500
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**OBS1:** para controlar a largura de tela onde o *Slider* aparece configure aqui

```
@media (max-width: 790px) { /* largura que vc quer que apareça */
    .carousel {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    etc.....
}
```

**OBS2:** Aqui vc controla a velocidade do *Slider*

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 500 /* quanto maior o número mais devagar a transição */
})
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! <3